# How can you paraphrase this- 'She may have been being interviewed for a job'?

Tags: grammar

I got this rarely used sentence from the below link-

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-verbs/verb-phrases

> She may have been being interviewed for a job.

What are the other ways by which you can express this idea, but still with the **same meaning**?

Comment: The verb in the uppermost clause is "may". It is the only tensed verb in the sentence. All the other verbs are located in embedded subordinate clauses: She **may** [have [been [being [interviewed for a job]]]].

Comment: 99.9% of native speakers would avoid that construction and use **maybe** or **perhaps**:  *Perhaps she was being interviewed.*.

Comment: Your edit has changed the topic of your question. Which means that posting my last comment was a waste of time!

Comment: BillJ - No .It wasn't. I understood the answer. Thankyou. That's no more a doubt for me. So I was trying to change the question into something else.

Answer (score 1):

This form is not so rare as one might think.

**What was she doing when you entered the room?**

**To be interviewed for a job**: see passive below

She may have been being interviewed for a job. [when some x occurred or was occurring]

What were they saying when the news of the accident was announced?

**To be questioned by [someone]**: see passive below

They may have been being questioned by the police at that point.

The passives: being questioned, being interviewed, being told, being groomed (dogs), for example, easily lend themselves to: may have been + being been (**action verb in passive**). This is common in speech.

There are no "other ways" to express these ideas. It is used to express something that may have been being done at a particular time in the past.